# Why will the screen change when i click the button but change to the original when i release it?

Tags: python, pygame

this code when run changes the screen but changes to the original one when i release my mouse why does this happen?when i comment out the `screen.blit(bg,(0,0))`and when i click it it works and changes to the other screen normally here is the code to show the problem:

```py
import pygame
import os

game = False
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((3840, 2160))
running = True
os.chdir(r"C:\Users\tomarj\OneDrive - Tata Advanced Systems Limited\Desktop\War Crime")

pygame.display.set_caption("GermanBall")
bg = pygame.image.load("Tan.jpg")
icon = pygame.image.load("box.png")
button1 = pygame.image.load("shirt.png").convert_alpha()
bg_new = pygame.image.load("big.jpg")

pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

class Button():
    def __init__(self, x, y, image, scale):
        width = image.get_width()
        height = image.get_height()
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (int(width * scale), int(height * scale)))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = (x, y)

    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(self.image, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y))

stat = Button(1550, 700, button1, 0.5)

while running:
    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    if stat.rect.collidepoint(pos):
        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 1:
            game = True
            if game:
                new_screen = pygame.display.set_mode((3840, 2160))
                new_screen.blit(bg_new, (0, 0))
                pygame.display.update()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            pygame.quit()

    screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    stat.draw()
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score -1):

At every frame (iteration of the while loop (`while running`)) The screen is being painted over (`blit`) with `bg`. You are also checking if the mouse is pressed and if so, you are 'blitting' `bg_new`. However this `blit` gets overridden by the `blit` at the end of the loop hence why after you release, the screen goes back to `bg`.

Comment: so the solution would be?

Comment: You haven't stated what your goal was. You just posted an observation.

Comment: my problem has been fixed